# Texture on pyvista polydata (trapezoid) looks crooked along a diagonal

Tags: python, opengl, vtk, pyvista

I have a pyvista polygon (specifically [an isosceles trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid)) and I want to apply a texture on it. The problem is that orignally parallel lines are weirdly crooked along a diagonal of the trapezoid. Is there any way to prevent this? I also do not really know yet whether this problem should be tackled on the pyvista, vtk or opengl layer. See below for a minimal working example to reproduce the problem.

Original texture:
[image: Original texture]
Expected outcome (more or less, it's not about the brightness, but the lines):
[image: Expected outcome]
Result/actual outcome of code below:
[image]

Code to reproduce the result:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

vertices = np.array([[0.2, 0, 0],
                     [0.8, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0]]) 

# mesh faces
faces = np.hstack([[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]])  # square

surf = pv.PolyData(vertices, faces)

tex = pv.read_texture("parallel.png")
# Turning these on did not make a visible difference.
tex.InterpolateOn()
tex.MipmapOn()
surf.t_coords = np.array([[0., 0.],
                          [1., 0.],
                          [1., 1.],
                          [0., 1.]])

# experience a weird bend in the texture
surf.plot(texture=tex)
```

Comment: The issue is caused, because you draw 2 independent triangles. The texture is correctly wrapped to each triangle separately. What you want to achieve is some kind of [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some texture distortion due to the low polygon count.
In my opinion, you could 1) rework your texture coordinates to sort of "sample" the texture:

```py
...
surf.t_coords = np.array([[0.2, 0.],
                          [0.8, 0.],
                          [1., 1.],
                          [0., 1.]])
...
```

[image]

Or 2) increase the number of vertices/triangles and adapt your UV coordinates accordingly. It should mitigate the distortion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am aware of solution 1), however this is unfortunately not what I want. Regarding option 2: could you explain how the polygon count influences the texture distortion?

Comment: Here is an interesting reading that explains the distortion issue better than I do and also how it is possible to solve this by using quads.: http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/

Sorry I would need some time to illustrate 2) but I expect the influence of the distortion to decrease as the disconticontinuity between the triangles in the model space decreases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the blog post, it describes exactly my problem!